# Как изменить свойство enabled для всех компонентов объединенных в groupbox?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Нужно изменить свойство `enabled` для всех компонентов (TextEdit, ComboBox и т.д.), объединенных в groupbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Т.к. `TGroupBox` унаследован от `TWinControl`, у него есть свойство `Controls` - массив всех контролов, лежащий внутри него. В цикле перебираете все (индексы от 0 до `ControlCount`-1) и меняете `Enabled`

PS Свойство `Enabled` отсутствует у компонентов (`TComponent`). Оно появляется только у контролов (`TControl`)

Comment: var I, K, x: Integer; 
    ChildGroupBox, ChildControl : TControl;
begin
 for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
   begin
     if Components[i] is TGroupBox then
       for k := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
        begin      
           ChildControl := Controls[k];
           if ChildControl.Name = 'gbHeader'  then               
           for x := 0 to gbHeader.ControlCount -1  do
           begin
             ChildGroupBox := gbHeader.Controls[x];
             ChildGroupBox.Enabled  := True;            
           end; 
        end; 
   end;         
end;

Comment: У меня остался один вопрос `if ChildControl.Name = 'gbHeader'  then for x := 0 to gbHeader.ControlCount -1  do` в самом цикле я указал сам объект. Какой тип нужно объявить, чтобы можно было заюзать вместо имя объекта переменную?  например `_VariableName.ControlCount -1`

Comment: `_VariableName: TControl`

Comment: Но я не могу понять, зачем вы ищите, ChildControl.Name = 'gbHeader', если у вас и так есть gbHeader?

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня на фрэйме есть 4 GroupBox , а в некоторых GroupBox не все контролы нужно сделать активными.

Comment: Пробовал я _VariableName: TControl ....  <br/>`ChildControl := Controls[k];`  <br/>
           `for x := 0 to _VariableName.ControlCount -1  do`  <br/>  подчеркивает красным и не понимает, что есть такое свойство `ControlCount`

Comment: Прошу прощения. В ответе написал, а в комментарии перепутал. `TWinControl`. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/Controls.TWinControl.ControlCount